# Clone from a Gitlab community private repo using a private token in Python script

Tags: python, gitlab, gitpython

I'd like to be able to clone a private git repository hosted on a Gitlab community edition providing my private token.
I tried using gitpython library and i can do the following :

```
from os.path import abspath
from git import Repo
to_path = abspath("C:\mypath\test")
Repo.clone_from("http://gitlab-ci-token:my_CI_token@myurl/testgroup/test.git", to_path)
```

This is working and clones the repo nicely.
The problem is that I want to use my private token and not the CI token of the repository. And this is not working :

```
Repo.clone_from("http://my_login:my_private_token@myurl/testgroup/test.git", to_path)
```

I even tried to use my password but couldn't get it to work neither.

If i want to use my private token it's because my script tries to clone all the repositories stored in a Gitalb group (here testgroup) and I don't know beforehand repositories that will be there so I can't get their CI token in the script.

I'll take any solution that let me clone a repository with a Login/private_token or a login/password without interactive authentication.

Comment: This is what SSH access has been built for, so consider using an SSH key setup!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by:

> I even tried to use my password but couldn't get it to work neither.

Setting your username and password in the URL should work:

```
Repo.clone_from("https://myself%40example.net:password@gitlab.example.com/username/repo.git", to_path)
```

Also, instead of having passwords stored in your source code, you should consider cloning your repos using SSH, or using the [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) system.

Comment: It actually works with login/password if you don't have some shitty company provided password with an @ inside.